# iOS 14.7.1 + Exchange 2019 - Server certificate no longer trusted

Tags: exchange, certificate, ios

After upgrade to iOS 14.7.1 I am no longer able to sync my email/calendar/contacts with company Exchange 2019.

Our Exchange uses certificate issued by our enterprise CA and these seem to become untrusted after the upgrade to iOS 14.7.1.

I tried multiple procedures:

- Manually imported the .pfx certificate from Exchange into iPhone
- Manually set the trust as per (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477) but the certificate/profile is not shown here
- Tried extracting/converting into .cer and import to iPhone - did not work

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: How long is the validity period of the server certificate? For web sites Apple only accepts certificate with about a year or less. May be that verification scheme is also applied to other connections as well?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, here are some suggestions for your reference:

1. Have you tried to re-add the emails account and check if this issue
   continues?
2. Does this issue occur when you add another account in this iphone or
   add the account  in another mobile device?
3. What results are returned when you run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365) to test
   activesync?

In addition, here are some troubleshooting steps on this issue for your refernce as well: [12 Fixes to Make iPhone Sync With Exchange Server](https://www.akruto.com/fix-iphone-not-syncing-with-exchange/)